# How to perform an activity using Jquery on page load

Tags: jquery

I have below code in Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // bind to cells with an ID attribute
    $("table > tbody > tr > td[id]").mouseover(function() {

        // grab the anchor from the LI whose ID starts with the cell's ID
        var $tooltip = $("div:hidden li[id^=" + $(this).attr("id") + "] a");

        // append it to the current cell
        $(this).append($tooltip);
    }).mouseout(function() {

        // remove the anchor/tooltip
        $(this).find("a").remove();
    });
});
```

Now you can see in above code that certain things has been done on **MOUSEOVER** event. The issue is that it does not show my anchor tag until I have **MOUSEOVER** on that particular **TD**. I want when my page gets loaded it will show all the anchor in **TD** without any **MOUSEOVER** or any **EVENTS**.

I want to write this code on page load event, please suggest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `mouseover` with `each` and youll have the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.map( $("table > tbody > tr > td"), function(elem){
    var tooltip = $("div:hidden li[id^=" + $(elem).attr("id") + "] a");
    $(elem).append(tooltip);
  });
});
```